# EventRelation - Retain record of contact's account relationship when contact added to event

Tags: trigger, visual-workflow, event, accountcontactrelation

I am looking for a way to capture the Account associated with a Contact at the time the Contact is added to an Event.  Currently, the Account gets updated in the EventRelation object when the Contact's Account changes.  This is a problem because we want to know the Account the Contact was associated with when added to the Event.

An idea I am thinking of pursuing is the creation of a custom object that will function similar to EventRelation but give me control of keeping the AccountID static once a Contact is added to the Event.  I would like to be able to handle this with a Flow, but I don't see a way to trigger the flow based on changes to the EventRelation table.  Is there a way to do that via a Flow or is a custom trigger needed?

Other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by

- creating a custom object with two fields - EventWhoRelation ID and Account ID
- created a flow that is triggered when an event is created or updated and the WhoCount is greater than 0
- I collect records from the EventWhoRelation table that match with the event id
- For each record in the collection, I search my new object to see if there is a record with a matching EventWhoRelation ID
- If there isn't a match, I create a record in my new object that contains the EventWhoRelation ID and the Account ID

By taking these steps, I permanently capture the contact's account when the contact was added to the Event Name section.  I don't handle the situation if a contact is removed from an event or if an event is deleted.  In my use case, this doesn't matter since I am simply using my new object to have a record of what the contact's account was when the contact was added to the event.